# how can I add Spring effect to Button like the button in hay day?

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, ngui

I want to add Spring effect to Button just like the button in Hay Day, could you give a hand?

when press the button, it will became 0.9 smaller, when release the button, it will back to original scale with spring effect, just like HayDay button.

I try to use iTween.PunchScale, but is is not similar to HayDay and it is punch back to origin scale (0.9 smaller when Press).

Could you give a hand?
[image]

Comment: The tags seem to indicate you're using NGUI? If so, that already has button tweens available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can us UIButtonScale which will modify scale of you button on hover & press.